# It says that it is "unable to get the vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am facing an issue in excel VBA. It says that it is `unable to get the vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class`

```
Private Sub cmb_Product_Change()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master")
    
    
    If Me.cmb_Product.Value = "" Or Me.cmb_Type.Value = "" Then Me.txt_Rate.Value = ""
    emphasized text[enter image description here][1]
       
    If Me.cmb_Type.Value = "Sale" Then
        Me.txt_Rate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, sh.Range("B:D"), 2, 0)
    ElseIf Me.cmb_Type.Value = "Purchase" Then
        Me.txt_Rate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, sh.Range("B:D"), 3, 0)
       
    End If



End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Probably there is no match.

Comment: Check this https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/worksheetfunction-and-errors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` if the lookup value cannot be found.

You have 2 possibilities:
(a) Ignore the error

```
Dim rate As Double  ' Or String, not sure what your data is.
On Error Resume Next
rate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, sh.Range("B:D"), 2, false)
On Error Goto 0
Me.txt_Rate.Value = rate
```

If your product is not found, rate will be empty

(b) Use `Application.VLookup` instead. This will not throw a runtime error, but it will return an Error as result if no match is found. Note that you need to declare the result as Variant, else you will get a Type Mismatch error (Error 13).

```
Dim rate As Variant
rate = Application.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, sh.Range("B:D"), 2, false)
if not isError(rate) then Me.txt_Rate.Value = rate
```

Update: For more details see this article: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/worksheetfunction-and-errors/